# Function Grapher in Python 3.4 says 'float is not interpreted as an integer'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing, python-3.4

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("FUNCTION GRAPHER")
def graph(formula,domain):
    x = np.array(domain)
    y = eval(formula)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
formula=input("Function: ")
domainmin=float(input("Min X Value: "))
domainmax=float(input("Max X Value: "))
graph(formula, range(domainmin,domainmax))
```

This is my code to create a grapher. As you can see the user can type in the function, and the domain. I am testing it with a simple y=x function, and this is the Error I get. I'm guessing it has something to do with how I set up the input.

```
FUNCTION GRAPHER
Function: x
Min X Value: -1
Max X Value: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Science/PYTHON/Grapher.py", line 12, in <module>
    graph(formula, range(domainmin,domainmax))
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

After the error occurs I type this:

```
graph('x', range(-1,10))
```

And the graph pops up. I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: This seems to simple to post as an answer (I feel like I'm missing something), but don't you just want to read the range in as an int, rather than a float: `domainmin=int(input("Min X Value: "))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range):

> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers

So to use `range` in this case you need to change your code to this:

```
domainmin=int(input("Min X Value: "))
domainmax=int(input("Max X Value: "))
```

Or, perhaps closer to what you intend, you can use instead [`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy-arange) or [`numpy.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html?highlight=linspace#numpy.linspace), so you can use `float` ranges - you will have to additionally add granulation parameter (`step` for `arange`) or number of steps (`num` for `linspace`).